# How can I run Moq tests with Visual Studio 2010 Express

Tags: visual-studio-2010, moq

I have installed VS2010 Express and C# Express Edition and MoQ.

I would like to know how can I execute the MoQ tests in class library without using the paid for version of VS2010?

I know NUnit has a UI, does MoQ have something similar, or is it just not possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In whatever project you wrote unit tests for NUnit, just add a reference to the Moq dll and you should be able to code the stubs/mocks there just fine. There is no UI for Moq. However, with the reference added to the unit test project, when you use the NUnit UI it will execute the code that uses Moq.

Answer (score 2):

You should have no problem at all using `Moq` with `Visual Studio 2010`, whichever edition it is you're using. Moq is a mocking framework, not a test framework. You don't write Moq test, you write tests with a unit test framework like `NUnit`, `MBUnit`, etc. that use objects (classes, interfaces, etc) mocked (simulated) with Moq.

I assume we're talking about *[this Moq](http://code.google.com/p/moq/)*, aren't we?

In case we are, you might want to take a look at [Moq's Quick Start page](http://code.google.com/p/moq/wiki/QuickStart).